# Split string into blocks based on certain length

Tags: python

Suppose we have a string `hello, today!`. I want to be able to do something like:

```
for x in range (2,20):
```

so that if x is equal to 3, for example, I will have a list that contains every 3rd letter like:

```
hl d!
eota
l,oy
```

The string I actually have is very long, and I just want the simplest method to accomplish this task for any x.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
>>> s = 'hello, today!'
>>> n = 3
>>> [s[i::n] for i in range(n)]
['hl d!', 'eota', 'l,oy']
```

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
'hello, today!'[::3]
```

this returns `'hl d!'`